# Is "I got thinking" correct?

Tags: grammar, informal-language

Is it correct to say

> "I got thinking about all my mistakes"

instead of "I started thinking about all my mistakes"?

I've heard "It got me thinking about...", which sounds quite informal but I believe is regularly used and accepted. However I'm unsure if "got thinking" would fall into the same category or if it's just completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

'I started thinking about *something*' is standard English, and acceptable in formal writing and also casual relaxed informal writing and speech.

'I got thinking about *something*' is informal and should probable be avoided in school work, formal writing, etc.

'I got **to** thinking about *something*' is very informal.

Comment: I must strongly disagree with this answer. See my answer for my views.

Answer (score 0):

"I got **to** thinking is more correct and acceptable than "I got thinking". In this case

> I got to thinking about all my mistakes

is the same as

> I started thinking about all my mistakes

Answer (score -1):

No.

> - (1) I started thinking about {something}.
> - (2) I got thinking about {something}.
> - (3) I got **to** thinking about {something}.
> - (4) It got me thinking about {something}.

Sentence (1) is indeed standard English, acceptable in all registers from very informal speech to formal academic writing. It is also natural, adn a fluent speaker might well say or write this.

Sentence (3) is rather informal, but it does occur in casual speech, nd might well occur in casual or semi-formal writing. A fluent speaker might well use this in an appropriate register.

Sentence (4) is somewhat informal, but quite natural. But the meaning is significantly different from (1) or (3). Here then speaker refers to some event, presumably mentioned previously, that stated him or her thinking.

Sentence (2) however, is not natural at all. Indeed I am inclined to call it flat-out wrong. "*I got thinking*" ought logically to mean "I have obtained thinking*" or perhaps "I have contracted thinking" (as if it were a disease. But tht is not the intended meaning. The intended meaning is sentence (3), this is simply an error.

Comment: "Pop Art, a sad, surreal tale about a juvenile delinquent becoming friends with an inflatable boy, was the first story he wrote that made him feel like he was in the right place. "That story came about because I got thinking about the phrase pop art, and I thought what if it did? So I wrote a story about an art that can pop," 2010 Guardian interview with the writer Joe Hill (son of Stephen King)

Comment: 'Some days I wonder why I am a Christian. In a secular age, it isn’t great for your career (as someone told me last week, “Admitting you’re a Christian in my circles is professional suicide”). In some countries, claiming the faith can literally sign your death sentence. And there are so many alternatives in the religious marketplace now.

So, why do I believe? I got thinking about this while preparing another Pause for Thought spot on BBC Radio 2. A memory of a close call in the Dominican Republic helped bring my reasons down to two. ' (Sheridan Voysey UK writer & broadcaster)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The examples you've picked are interesting. In both cases it could be interpreted as something like "I got [engrossed in] thinking about X." I wonder if it should be interpreted as  a description of the beginning of a thought process which has ended up going on for an unexpectedly long time.

Comment: @Zwuwdz - I don't know whether the thought process which is dexcribed has necessarily to go on for  long, but I think that very often we use 'I got thinking about _something_' when we are describing a thought process that was productive in some way, or which led to some notable result, insight, decision, etc.